# VBA:: checking values from one array to another

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

I am trying to write a VBA code that cross checks all of the values in one array with another (X with Y) and to copy the value into a new array if it is duplicated (FinalResults).  So far I have the following code and would greatly appreciate some guidance on how to write it correctly.

```
Function lnArray(X as Variant, Y as Variant) As Variant
Dim counter1 As Integer
Dim data As Integer
Dim FinalResults() As Variant

For counter1 = 1 To Max
    For Each data In X
        If data.Value = Y.Value Then
            counter1 = counter1 + 1
            ReDim Preserve FinalResults(counter1)
            FinalResults(counter1) = data.Value
        End If
    Next data
Next counter1
End Function
```

Comment: Must the original arrays be preserved? What size do they have?

Comment: I feels like a [million variations](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vba]+unique+array) on this question been answered on SO already. Can you not find inspiration in any of them? Most questions are about retaining the unique values, while you want to do the opposite, namely retain the non-unique values. Any of the solutions linked to above can probably be adapted to do what you want by adding a well-placed `Not` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I saw when I looked over the code was, that `Max` is neither declared nor initialized. Even if I assume that `Option Explicit` is not set, this for-next loop runs from 1 to 0, which means no loops at all. I guess that's not what you intended?

Second is, your `FinalResult` array is declared locally in this function, hence no kind of result value can be returned to the calling function.